# Creating a table using mathematical equations Pandas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Based on the dictionary below I want to create a new DataFrame function of all of the unique stocks being META and BABA. The Number of Buys and Sells corresponds to the Buying and selling of a symbol.

I would also like to make a column that tracks the `Gains/Loss` of that stock that being it will subtract the buy value from sell value (Buy - Sell) like `(2360.15-2160.36) + (1897-1936.2)` since META was bought and sold twice on 2 different occasions the value is gonna be like that.

Last but not least I would like to make the % Gain/Loss that is calculated by the equation (Buy-Sell)/Buy * 100 so for the META the equation would be like
`((2360.15-2160.36)/2360.15 + (1897-1936.2)/1897)* 100)`. How would I be able to modify the table below to get the expected Outputs?

```
import pandas as pd 
a = {'Date': {0: '2/4/2022 1:33:40 PM', 1: '2/7/2022 3:09:46 PM', 2: '2/11/2022 9:35:44 AM', 3: '2/14/2022 2:55:33 PM', 4: '2/15/2022 3:55:33 PM', 5:  '2/15/2022 9:15:33 PM'},
     'TransactionType': {0: 'Buy', 1: 'Buy', 2: 'Sell', 3: 'Sell', 4: 'Buy', 5:'Sell'},
     'Symbol': {0: 'META', 1: 'BABA', 2:'META', 3: 'BABA',4: 'META', 5: 'META' },
     'Price': {0: 12.79, 1: 116.16, 2: 12.93, 3: 121.82, 4: 13.55, 5:13.83},
     'Amount': {0: -2366.15, 1: -2439.36, 2: -2160.0, 3: 2558.22, 4:-1897, 5:1936.2}}

print((2360.15-2160.36) + (1897-1936.2))
print(2439.36-2558.22)

print(((2360.15-2160.36)/2360.15 + (1897-1936.2)/1897)* 100)
print(((2439.36-2558.22)/2439.36) * 100)
```

Current data table:

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) We could use `groupby` + `count` + `unstack` to get the number of buys and sells for each "Symbol"

(ii) We could create pairs from buy-sells using `eq` + `groupby` + `cumsum`; then `groupby` these pairs along with "Symbols" to get the `Gains/Losses` and "Percentage change" columns:

```
out = df.groupby(['Symbol','TransactionType'])['TransactionType'].count().unstack().add_prefix('Number of ').add_suffix('s')
g = df.groupby(['Symbol', df['TransactionType'].eq('Buy').groupby(df['Symbol']).cumsum()])['Amount']
out['Gains/Losses'] = g.sum().groupby(level=0).sum()
out['Percentage change'] = g.pct_change().groupby(df['Symbol']).sum()
out = out.reset_index().rename_axis([None], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Symbol  Number of Buys  Number of Sells  Gains/Losses  Percentage change
0   BABA               1                1        118.86          -2.048726
1   META               2                2       -166.95          -3.933540
```

Note that the number I get here are different from the numbers you have in the expected output because the input DataFrame you supplied is different from the DataFrame you used in your analysis.